# How to prevent Eclipse from flagging file as erroneous

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, validation, ide

I have a file called "build_properties.xml" in my Java project, which is not a valid XML file, and it is not meant to be. It's included by a build system in another place, so I don't want to touch that file. But it is still a part of the Eclipse project.

By default, Eclipse  didn't try to validate that "build_properties.xml" is actually an XML file, but I accidentally clicked on "Validate". Now it marks this file, and the whole project, as having an error, with the little red "X" icon. This makes it difficult to spot actual errors.

I want Eclipse to ignore the XML validation error. I don't want to change the name of the file or its contents. How do I do this?

(I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, build id 20090920-1017.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`right click on project > Properties > Validation > XML Validator > Settings (...)` and add your xml to the exclusion list

Comment: Don't forget to re-validate the project to get the red errors to disappear after you add exclusions. Right-click project -> Validate to force it.  Also, to add exclusion, in Settings as Bozho said, highlight "Exclude Group" then click "Add Rule". To add a folder, click the "Folder or file name" -> Next -> Browse Folder (button) -> Finish.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in Luna. It has an XML Syntax under the Validators but there is no option to exclude files only select the types of xml errors.